# Ubuntu Server 14.04: No login with new MariaDB users

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, mariadb

I have a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system and installed MariaDB on it (version 5.5.36-1) whichI can access with the root user through phpMyAdmin.
When I now create a new user in phpMyAdmin and then try to login with it, the logon fails and I see the following message in the error log of MariaDB:

> 'user' entry 'new_user@%' has both a password and an authentication plugin specified. The password will be ignored.

Do you have an idea what the problem might be and how to solve it?

Thanks and regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 3):

OK, meanwhile I solved the mistery.
If I create the user in the shell directly with SQL, the new user works as expected.
The second solution would be to create the user with phpMyAdmin and then go to table mysql.user and clear the field "plugin" for the newly created user.